# Serialize Range with Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, jackson2

I have a `Range` that I need to serialize in a certain format, namely `"[lower,upper)"`.  To do so I have written a basic serializer:

```
public class RangeSerializer extends StdSerializer<Range<?>> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(final Range<?> value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    if (value != null) {
      gen.writeRaw('"');
      gen.writeRaw('[');
      provider.defaultSerializeValue(value.lowerEndpoint(), gen);
      gen.writeRaw(',');
      provider.defaultSerializeValue(value.upperEndpoint(), gen);
      gen.writeRaw(')');
      gen.writeRaw('"');
    }
  }
```

(Note that in reality the serializer handles the various possibilities of `Range` such as closed/open ranges, the possibility of unbounded ranges at either end, etc. but for the purposes of my question that's not relevant so I've removed it to keep the code simple).

My problem is that by falling back to the default serializer for each class I end up with quotes in the wrong place.  For example, if I had a `Range<String>` with an entry `"[foo,bar)"` then when serializing it I obtain `"["foo","bar")"`.  I need the result without quotes around the lower and upper endpoint values.

I understand that the additional quotes are because `gen.writeString()` in the underlying serializer doesn't realize that it's already in a string.  Is there some way to let the generator know this, or an alternative way to achieve what I'm attempting to do?

Note that `Range<?>` really is generic, so I can't hard-code the serialization of the values.  It needs to work for `Range<Integer>`, `Range<String>`, `Range<DateTime>` and anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get your approach of using a single generator to serialize everything working. You might be able to use a `DelegatingJsonGenerator` and hook certain calls, but I decided the way shown below was significantly simpler (at the price of minor performance loss).

Here's a Spock test class demonstrating how I was able to get this working.

```
@Grab('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.1')
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class RangeSerializationTest extends Specification {

    static class Range<T> {
        T lower
        T upper
    }

    @JsonSerialize(converter = RangeConverter)
    static interface RangeMixin {
    }

    static class RangeConverter extends StdConverter<Range, String> {
        private static final mapper = new ObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)

        @Override
        String convert(Range value) {
            def lower = mapper.convertValue(value.lower, String)
            def upper = mapper.convertValue(value.upper, String)
            return "[$lower,$upper)"
        }
    }


    @Unroll
    def 'range of #lower.class'() {
        given:
        def mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        mapper.addMixIn(Range, RangeMixin)

        expect:
        mapper.writeValueAsString(new Range(lower: lower, upper: upper)) == expectedJson

        where:
        lower         | upper         | expectedJson
        'abc'         | 'def'         | '"[abc,def)"'
        123           | 456           | '"[123,456)"'
        new Date(123) | new Date(456) | '"[1970-01-01T00:00:00.123+0000,1970-01-01T00:00:00.456+0000)"'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  A converter is an interesting way of doing things, but can it be registered in the same way that serializers and deserializers can be registered or does it have to be attached with an annotation?  I don't have access to the Range class itself, and the range is in fact being used as the key for a map, so I'm not sure if an annotation-based solution will help me here.

Comment: Use a mixin to add the annotation to the Range class.  I've edited my answer to show how.  Note the `addMixin(...)` part configured on the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this question in the future, good news! As of Jackson 2.17, native support for serializing Guava's Range with this format has been added. To achieve the desired serialization format, you can now annotate your property with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)`.

```
class Stringified<T extends Comparable<?>> {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    public Range<T> r;

    public Stringified(Range<T> r) {
        this.r = r;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class RangeSerializationExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new GuavaModule());

        // Example with open range
        mapper.writeValueAsString(new Stringified<>(Range.open(1, 10))); // Output: {"r":"(1..10)"}

        // Example with closed range
        mapper.writeValueAsString(new Stringified<>(Range.closed(5, 15))); // Output: {"r":"[5..15]"}

        // Example with unbounded range
        mapper.writeValueAsString(new Stringified<>(Range.all())); // Output: {"r":"(-∞..+∞)"}
    }
}
```